# Multi threaded core-data and logging

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, core-data, logging

**Background info**

I've almost completed my app. Everything was working perfectly. Then the client asked for logging in the app (i.e. various points that had to record what was done, what responses were, etc...).

The app allows the user to create "messages" which are saved into core-data. The messages are then uploaded to the server individually. The message are created on the main thread and uploaded in an `NSOperation` subclass on a background thread.

It is the same template for the `NSOperation` subclass that I have used before and works. I'm doing all the best practise stuff for multi-threaded core-data.

All this side of the app works fine.

I added the logging part of the app. I've created a singleton called `MyLogManager` and a `CoreData` entity called `LogEntry`. The entity is very simple, it only has a `date` and `text`.

**Code**

The function inside the MyLogManager is...

```
- (void)newLogWithText:(NSString*)text
{
    NSLog(@"Logging: %@", text);

    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self context];

    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"LogEntry" inManagedObjectContext:context];

    LogEntry *logEntry = [[LogEntry alloc] initWithEntity:entity insertIntoManagedObjectContext:context];

    logEntry.text = text;
    logEntry.date = [NSDate date];

    [self saveContext:context];
}
```

which in turn runs...

```
- (NSManagedObjectContext*)context
{
    AppDelegate *appDelegate = (ThapAppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSConfinementConcurrencyType];
    [managedObjectContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator:appDelegate.persistentStoreCoordinator];

    return managedObjectContext;
}
```

and

```
- (void)saveContext:(NSManagedObjectContext*)context
{
    MyAppDelegate *appDelegate = (MyAppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:appDelegate
                                             selector:@selector(mergeChanges:)
                                                 name:NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification
                                               object:context];

    NSError *error = nil;
    if ([context hasChanges] && ![context save:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Unhandled error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:appDelegate name:NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification object:context];
}
```

The NSOperation main thread (well parts of it)...

```
- (void)main
{
    //create context and retrieve NSManagedObject using the NSManagedObjectID passed in as a parameter to operation

    self.message.lastSendAttempt = [NSDate date];

    [self startUpload];

    [self completeOperation]; //This doesn't get run because the startUpload method never returns
}

- (void)startUpload
{
    [[MyLogManager sharedInstance] logSendingMessageWithURLParameters:[self.event URLParameters]]; //this is a convenience method. It just appends some extra info on the string and runs newLogWithText.

    //Do some uploading stuff here...
    //The operation stops before actually doing the upload when logging to CoreData.
}
```

**The problem**

My `NSOperation` subclass that uploads the messages (on a background thread) calls this `newLogWithText` function but it also updates the message it is uploading. The `NSOperation` uses the same methods to get and save the core-data context. (i.e. it updates the last sent date and also updates if the send was successful).

This is the first time I've tried to deal with simultaneous writes and saves to core-data.

I don't get any errors and the app carries on "working". But the operation never completes. I've tried to debug it with breakpoints but when I use breakpoints it works. Without breakpoints the operation never finishes and the upload never happens. And then it just sits there blocking the queue it is on and no other messages can be sent.

In my `appDelegate` (I know this isn't the ideal place for it but it's the default for a new project and I haven't changed it) the `mergeChanges` method is just...

```
- (void)mergeChanges:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    [self.managedObjectContext performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:) withObject:notification waitUntilDone:NO];
}
```

I've tried throwing the 'newLogWithText' function off to another thread and even to the main thread with no luck.

I'm just about to try it now but change the "waitUntilDone" of the merge to YES. (Just noticed this). (This didn't work).

I'm 90% certain this is down to simultaneous writes to different contexts and the conflict resolution as it is the first time I've dealt with this. If I comment out the `newLogWithText` function then everything works as it should.

The only alternative at the moment is to scrap the `LogEntry` from core data and save the logs into an array inside `NSUserDefaults` but that doesn't feel right. Is there another way?

**EDIT**

I've changed it now so it users `NSUserDefaults` and it works without a problem. It just feels like a hacky solution.

Comment: Do you have a separate context for each thread? It doesn't look like it from the code you posted above.

Comment: Yes, the method above `-(NSManagedObjectContext*)context` creates a new context using the persistent store from the appDelegate. This is run each time it is required (i.e. each NSOperation runs this within itself as it is on a new thread).

Comment: If you don't need to save log entries in Core Data, I would take a look at [CocoaLumberjack](https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaLumberjack). In addition, also @Rog advice is correct.

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look at CocoaLumberjack :D

Comment: Could yo also show where you call `newLogWithText`? Is this called inside the `main` of `NSOperation` subclass?

Comment: Hi, yes this is called in the main method of the operation but after I have written to the context within the NSOperation. Will add a bit of code...

Comment: Yeah I also think it's a bit heavyweight using Core Data for logging; you want something that's less likely to fail.  Create a simple class that writes to a text file that can be easily uploaded at the of the session.

Comment: Thanks, will def look at an alternative then :D Thanks all.